# Intentionally get a "MySQL server has gone away" error

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to cope with MySQL's error [`MySQL server has gone away`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) in a django env.

The quick workaround was to set the global [`wait_timeout` MySQL variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) to a huge value, but in the long run this would accumulate to many open connections.

I figured I'll get the `wait_timeout` variable and poll the server in smaller intervals. After implementing this I tried to test it but am failing to get the error.

I `set global wait_timeout=15` and even `set global interactive_timeout=15` but the connection refuses to disappear. I'm sure I'm polling the database in larger intervals than 15sec.

What could be the cause for not being able to recreate this error?

Comment: +1 for wanting to test error conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Run below dirty-and-quick script and test your django project or whatever. I think this is not an elegant approach, but it works well.

```
<?php
mysql_connect( "127.0.0.1", "id", "pw" ); // should be changed to yours
while(1)
{
    $r = mysql_query( "SHOW PROCESSLIST" );
    while( $d = mysql_fetch_row( $r ) ) 
    {   
        if( $d[7] != "SHOW PROCESSLIST" )
        {   
            mysql_query( "KILL ". $d[0] );
            echo( $d[0]." was killed.\n" );
        }   
    }   
}
?>
```

And here is the result.

```
mysql> select * from foo;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    337
Current database: test

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    338
Current database: test

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few modifications to @lqez code to be used with mysqli:

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database"); //should be changed to yours

while (1) {
    $r = $mysql->query("SHOW PROCESSLIST");
    while ($d = $r->fetch_row()) {
        if ($d[7] != "SHOW PROCESSLIST") {
            $mysql->query("KILL " . $d[0]);
            echo($d[0] . " was killed.\n");
        }
    }
}
?>
```